# What am i doing wrong with .synopsis padding?

Tags: html, css

No matter how many times i set the padding of the .synopsis element to 0px to allow the text to align left it doesn't work when i test it in the browser. I want the title "Synopsis" to look like the title "Character", but it's not aligning left to the same level as "Character".

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.synopsisdivheader {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.synopsis {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.synopsisdiv {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
}

.charactersdiv {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.characters {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}


/*just want the word characters to be underlined*/

.characterdetails {
  /*from woody to forky*/
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*main section contains from synopsis to bo peep*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-color: yellow;
}

a {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.synopsis {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}

.title {
  background-color: rgb(220, 243, 245);
  text-decoration-color: maroon;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: rgb(161, 29, 0);
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1:hover,
h2:hover,
h3:hover,
a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.headerimage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.profileimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.quotesdiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 100px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(2, 154, 2);
}
```

```html
<div clas="parent">
  <img class="headerimage" src="toy story banner final.png" alt="Toy Story Banner Image">
  <img class="profileimage" src="toy story profile pic.jpg" alt="Toy Story profile image">
  <h1 class="title">Toy Story 4</h1>
</div>
<div class="synopsisdivheader">
  <!--Just want the h2 Synopsis to be underlined-->
  <h2 class="synopsis">Synopsis</h2>
</div>
<div class="synopsisdiv">
  <p class="synopsisdetails">Woody, Buzz Lightyear and the rest of the gang embark on a road trip with Bonnie and a new toy named Forky. The adventurous journey turns into an unexpected reunion as Woody's slight detour leads him to his long-lost friend Bo Peep. As Woody and Bo
    discuss the old days, they soon start to realize that they're worlds apart when it comes to what they want from life as a toy.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="charactersdiv">
    <!--Just want the h2 characters to be underlined-->
    <h2 class="characters">Characters</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="characterdetails">
    <h3>Woody</h3>
    <img src="woody 2.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Woody">
    <div class="p-one">
      <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000158/" target="_blank">Tom Hanks</a></p>
      <p>Woody is a smart, determined, and passionate man, and would do anything for his nearest and dearest friends. He considers his friends as family and he tries his best to keep them together at all times. Yet, he is a flawed character.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Buzz Lightyear</h3>
  <img src="buzzlightyear.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Buzz Lightyear">
  <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000741/" target="_blank">Tim Allen</a></p>
  <p>Buzz is a toy from a science fiction franchise of the same name. In his fictional backstory, Buzz is a universal space ranger from the Intergalactic Alliance and the captain of the Alliance's team. Buzz is trained in several forms of martial arts and
    is a highly skilled warrior in hand to hand combat.</p>
  <h3>Forky</h3>
  <img src="forky.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Forky">
  <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0355024/" target="_blank">Tony Hale</a></p>
  <p>Forky is a white plastic spork outfitted with a pair of different sized googly eyes; a mouth made out of blue plasticine; two halves of a popsicle stick for feet, stuck on with modelling clay; arms and hands made out of a red pipe cleaner; and a unibrow
    made out of red plasticine.</p>
  <h3>Bo Peep</h3>
  <img src="bo peep.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Bo Peep">
  <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001633/" target="_blank">Annie Potts</a></p>
  <p>"Little" Bo Peep is a character in the Toy Story franchise and a main character of the fourth film. She is a porcelain shepherdess figurine and Sheriff Woody's girlfriend in the films. Bo Peep and her sheep were originally adornments of Molly Davis'
    bedside lamp.</p>

  <div class=list>
    <p>Top five countries where Toy Story 4 grossed the highest during opening week:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>United States</li>
      <li>Canada</li>
      <li>Brazil</li>
      <li>India</li>
      <li>Nigeria</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="quotesdiv">
    <p>Woody:"Being there for a child is the best thing a toy can do."</p>
  </div>
  <!-- First Fieldset -->
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Comments</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="comments">Leave a comment!</label>
      <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments" required />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: You do realize you have the .synopsis multiple times in the css right? The last one will be used and it has padding-left: 100px.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS code contains .synopsis twice, and both times you have set different values for padding-left. CSS accepts the latest value, and the last CSS value for padding-left has padding-left set to 100px, hence it is putting up a 100px padding for Synopsis.

I have commented the CSS code that you need to remove in order to get your intended result. Hope this helps.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.synopsisdivheader {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.synopsis {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.synopsisdiv {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
}

.charactersdiv {
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.characters {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}


/*just want the word characters to be underlined*/

.characterdetails {
  /*from woody to forky*/
  background-color: rgb(14, 173, 225);
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*main section contains from synopsis to bo peep*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-color: yellow;
}

a {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

/*.synopsis {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}*/

.title {
  background-color: rgb(220, 243, 245);
  text-decoration-color: maroon;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: rgb(161, 29, 0);
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1:hover,
h2:hover,
h3:hover,
a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.headerimage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.profileimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.quotesdiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 100px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(2, 154, 2);
}
```

```html
<div clas="parent">
  <img class="headerimage" src="toy story banner final.png" alt="Toy Story Banner Image">
  <img class="profileimage" src="toy story profile pic.jpg" alt="Toy Story profile image">
  <h1 class="title">Toy Story 4</h1>
</div>
<div class="synopsisdivheader">
  <!--Just want the h2 Synopsis to be underlined-->
  <h2 class="synopsis">Synopsis</h2>
</div>
<div class="synopsisdiv">
  <p class="synopsisdetails">Woody, Buzz Lightyear and the rest of the gang embark on a road trip with Bonnie and a new toy named Forky. The adventurous journey turns into an unexpected reunion as Woody's slight detour leads him to his long-lost friend Bo Peep. As Woody and Bo
    discuss the old days, they soon start to realize that they're worlds apart when it comes to what they want from life as a toy.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="charactersdiv">
    <!--Just want the h2 characters to be underlined-->
    <h2 class="characters">Characters</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="characterdetails">
    <h3>Woody</h3>
    <img src="woody 2.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Woody">
    <div class="p-one">
      <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000158/" target="_blank">Tom Hanks</a></p>
      <p>Woody is a smart, determined, and passionate man, and would do anything for his nearest and dearest friends. He considers his friends as family and he tries his best to keep them together at all times. Yet, he is a flawed character.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Buzz Lightyear</h3>
  <img src="buzzlightyear.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Buzz Lightyear">
  <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000741/" target="_blank">Tim Allen</a></p>
  <p>Buzz is a toy from a science fiction franchise of the same name. In his fictional backstory, Buzz is a universal space ranger from the Intergalactic Alliance and the captain of the Alliance's team. Buzz is trained in several forms of martial arts and
    is a highly skilled warrior in hand to hand combat.</p>
  <h3>Forky</h3>
  <img src="forky.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Forky">
  <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0355024/" target="_blank">Tony Hale</a></p>
  <p>Forky is a white plastic spork outfitted with a pair of different sized googly eyes; a mouth made out of blue plasticine; two halves of a popsicle stick for feet, stuck on with modelling clay; arms and hands made out of a red pipe cleaner; and a unibrow
    made out of red plasticine.</p>
  <h3>Bo Peep</h3>
  <img src="bo peep.jpg" width="100px 100px" alt="Bo Peep">
  <p>Played by <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001633/" target="_blank">Annie Potts</a></p>
  <p>"Little" Bo Peep is a character in the Toy Story franchise and a main character of the fourth film. She is a porcelain shepherdess figurine and Sheriff Woody's girlfriend in the films. Bo Peep and her sheep were originally adornments of Molly Davis'
    bedside lamp.</p>

  <div class=list>
    <p>Top five countries where Toy Story 4 grossed the highest during opening week:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>United States</li>
      <li>Canada</li>
      <li>Brazil</li>
      <li>India</li>
      <li>Nigeria</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="quotesdiv">
    <p>Woody:"Being there for a child is the best thing a toy can do."</p>
  </div>
  <!-- First Fieldset -->
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Comments</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="comments">Leave a comment!</label>
      <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments" required />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```